# Issue summing doubles in DataTable with VB?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, csv

I am having an issue summing a column of dollar amounts in a DataTable with VB. I have tried two different ways resulting in two different errors which I am not sure how to resolve. Before I go into the two ways I have tried to solve the problem here is the setup:

I am importing a tab delimited file into a DataTable. The headers are automatically populated with data from the first row in the file.
The DataGridView that displays the Datatable is called DGV_detail.

The column in DGV_detail I am trying to sum occurs at column 3 and is called 'Value-to-date'. This column is full of dollar amount values similar to: $10.00 With the dollar sign and everything.

I am also declaring a view variables and doing some calculations when a button is clicked.

Here is my first approach:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DGV_detail.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
    interestPaidToAccounts = interestPaidToAccounts + DGV_detail.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
Next
```

When I try this approach I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.
```

The other methods I was trying to use to solve the problem were (For reference: In these examples I created a variable local to the button_click function that assigned the BGV_detail.DataSource to equal dataTable1):

```
Dim sumObject = dataTable1.Compute("Sum(Convert(Value-to-date, 'System.Decimal'))", "[Value-to-date] IS NOT NULL")
```

and

```
Dim sumObject As Decimal = dataTable1.Compute("Sum(Value-to-date)", "")
```

Which both produced the following error:

```
Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.
```

I am pretty lost at this point so whatever the community thinks the best method to resolves these problems is, I am open to.

I can provide additional information if needed! :)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Dollar signs are most certainly not valid float values so that would be expected. Can you clean the data and modify the type before computing?

Comment: A column name with special characters needs to be wrapped in brackets. A dash will be interpreted as a subtraction operator otherwise.

Comment: Sounds almost entirely like a data typing issue. A DataGridView column can be set to hold doubles or decimals, but `DGV.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value` will always return object.  Set Option Strict On for starters

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign is the issue, use mid to remove it and val to convert to number:

```
val(mid(DGV_detail.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value, 2,DGV_detail.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.length -1))
```

Untested, but should get you started ... there are any number of ways to remove the $.